# Unable to Start Namenode, Secondary Namenode & Datanode

Tags: hadoop2.7.3

I have installed **Hadoop-2.7.3** on **VirtualBox**.

When I type the command `./start-all.sh` in the terminal, the `Namenode`, `Secondary Namenode` & `Datanode` were not starting. The below is the error screenshot. Please suggest some solution for this issue.

**Error I'm getting on my terminal window.**

```
sreenu@MyPC:~/hdfs/sbin$ ./start-all.sh

This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
17/07/24 16:38:12 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: ssh: connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 22: Connection refused

17/07/24 16:38:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

starting yarn daemons
resourcemanager running as process 2899. Stop it first.

localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

sreenu@MyPC:~/hdfs/sbin$ jps
3536 Jps
2899 ResourceManager
3175 JobHistoryServer

sreenu@MyPC:~/hdfs/sbin$
```

[Error I'm seeing on terminal window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuRGG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved on my machine by uninstalling and reinstalling the openssh-server and openssh-client.

Commands:

**sudo apt-get remove openssh-server openssh-client**

**sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client**

Close the Terminal, Restart your VirtualBox and try to start all daemons again.

Answer (score 0):

After installing ssh, you need to actually start the ssh server. The problem with your setup is that your ssh server is not running. To verify this issue run:

```sh
$ ssh localhost
```

If you get the same error, i.e. `localhost: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused`, then start the ssh service using the following command:

```sh
$ /etc/init.d/ssh start
```

If you do not get any error with `ssh localhost`, then there is some other issue.